# Calculating over records/rows found in different tables

Tags: mysql, mariadb

In MariaDB, if I have 300 tables that have an identical quantity of rows (basically names and the same names are in the same row positions/indeces across all tables) and each table has, say, three columns, how do I calculate an average, or any other calculation, for the third row item for just one name across all 300 tables?

`    TABLE 1                          TABLE 2

---

| NAMES | DATA 1 | SCORE |  | NAMES | DATA 1 | SCORE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Jim | 30 | 12 |  | Jim | 20 | 200 |
| John | 40 | 30 |  | John | 30 | 100 |
| Jill | 50 | 27 |  | Jill | 15 | 300 |
| Jerry | 20 | 50 |  | Jerry | 17 | 400 |
| Jack | 10 | 14 |  | Jack | 16 | 100 |

---

I am trying to calculate quantites (i.e. averages, standard deviations, and other custom calculations/formulae) for the "SCORE" for each name across all tables (two tables only shown for brevity) and then have such calculated quantities stored in a separate table that has each name listed.  So for instance, I'd like to be able to calculate the average "SCORE" for Jim across all 300 tables and store that in some separate results table that has a dedicated row for his name and then move down to the next name and do the same.

How would I do this/approach this?  I tried looking into UNIONS and and JOINS but couldn't see how to obtain what I'm looking for with those operations.

Comment: Unpivot the data (multiple UNIONs) then calculate needed aggregates. *for the third row item* Without ORDER BY any enumeration not exists. *across all 300 tables?* Dynamic SQL.

Comment: Union ALL then group by on name would seem to be the way to go so what problem did you have with Union? Also you don't say that the 300 table definitions are identical so in general terms how are they different?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: @Akina -  Thank you for your kind response.  Your approach worked.

Comment: @P.Salmon - I was able to get it resolved indeed using UNION after better understanding how multiple UNIONS should be structured.  Thank you for your kind response.